# How to convert Blender blend (or obj) file to .h file?

Tags: perl, opengl

I would like to convert a 3d model (`.obj` like blender) to `.h` file. there is a tool at github but when I run it, I got a message error :

tool:
https://github.com/HBehrens/obj2opengl/

my commend line:

```
C:\Users\***>perl C:\Users\***\Desktop\vuforia\obj2opengl.pl C:\
Users\***\Desktop\vuforia\cc.obj
```

`cc.obj` is an export of blender software .

error :

```
Can't use 'defined(@array)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?) at C:\Users\***\Desktop\vuforia\obj2opengl.pl line 118.
```

line 118 :

```
if(defined(@center)) { //line 118
    $xcen = $center[0];
    $ycen = $center[1];
    $zcen = $center[2];
}
```

I don't know where is the problem. 
my OS is windows 64 . I installed perl before .

Comment: In the github link that is line 154. That script is not a particularly good example of Perl. Which Perl version did you install on your Windows? Strawberry or ActivePerl? Which version number? In way older versions, that particular syntax was ok, but at some point `defined(@array)` was deprecated. Your Perl is so new that this is actually an error now. Try just removing the `defined` so the line says `if (@center) {`. The `@center` will return its number of elements, which would be 3, which is true, and then it will go into the block.

Comment: your answer true. please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't use 'defined(@array)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)

This tells you that the syntax `defined(@array)` is not valid, and even gives a hint. All you need to do is remove the `defined()`. Your code would then read

```
if(@center) {
    $xcen = $center[0];
    $ycen = $center[1];
    $zcen = $center[2];
}
```

The `if` evaluation forces the array into *scalar context*, which makes it return its number of elements. That's probably 3, or 0. If it's 0 then it's a false value and the block is skipped. 3 on the other hand is a true value and the block will be executed.

The `defined(@array)` syntax [was deprecated from Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html).

> Use of defined on aggregates (hashes and arrays) is deprecated. It used to report whether memory for that aggregate had ever been allocated. This behavior may disappear in future versions of Perl.

The version of Perl you installed is newer than the version the author of your script used, and this is a rare occasion of an incompatible change.

Comment: I cannot find which release deprecated the behaviour.

Comment: [Deprecated in **Perl v5.6.1** and fatal in **Perl v5.22.0**](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.22.0/pod/perldelta.pod#defined(@array)_and_defined(%hash)_are_now_fatal_errors)

Comment: Thanks @Borodin. It still says _deprecated_ in the 5.24 perldoc I quoted.